# Add sum of values of two lists into new one

Tags: python, list, sum

EDIT: Is it possible to be done without any imports?

This question already has an answer here but it doesn't mention what to do if the size of the lists is not the same

```
v1 = [1,2,3,4]
v2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need `sum = [2,4,6,8,5]`

I get a successful result from my code only if the lists are with the same size or [], but no success if the size is different no matter what i put in there

This is what I got

```
def addVectors(v1, v2):
    sum = []
    result = 0
    if len(v1) == 0 and len(v2) == 0:
        return sum
    elif len(v1) == len(v2) or len(v1) != len(v2):
        for i in range(len(v1)):
            result = v1[i] + v2[i]
            sum.append(result)

    return sum
```

Comment: Why no imports? `itertools` is in the standard library; it's just as much a part of Python as `len` or `list`.

Comment: @user2357112 just to see if its possible with a for/while loop and a bunch of if/elif statements no particular reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) with the fill value set to 0:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

summed = [a + b for a, b in izip_longest(v1, v2, fillvalue=0)]
```

The `izip_longest()` documentation gives you a pure-python, no imports needed version, provided you also take the `itertools.repeat()` and `itertools.chain()` functions in their pure-python form.

Or you could do:

```
def addVectors(v1, v2):
    min_length = min(len(v1), len(v2))
    result = [a + b for a, b in zip(v1, v2)]
    return result + v1[min_length:] + v2[min_length:]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> v1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> v2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [a + b for a, b in izip_longest(v1, v2, fillvalue=0)]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 5]
>>> def addVectors(v1, v2):
...     min_length = min(len(v1), len(v2))
...     result = [a + b for a, b in zip(v1, v2)]
...     return result + v1[min_length:] + v2[min_length:]
... 
>>> addVectors(v1, v2)
[2, 4, 6, 8, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `izip_longest` with a fill value of 0:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

v1 = [1,2,3,4]
v2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
res = [sum(items) for items in izip_longest(v1, v2, fillvalue=0)]
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 5]
```